# How to handle when __file__ is None and __path__ is List[str] of duplicates in native namespace package

Tags: python, namespaces, python-packaging

I am just converting a package to be compliant with [PEP 420 namespace packaging](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

One of the modules in the package pulls the `__file__` attribute for the module `foo.bar` to ultimately get the `foo.bar` directory path via `os.path.dirname(foo.bar.__file__)`.

However, it seems since removing some of the `__init__.py`, now the:

- `foo.bar.__file__ = None`

And

- `foo.bar.__path__ = _NamespacePath(['/path/to/foo/bar', '/path/to/foo/bar', '/path/to/foo/bar'])`

This leads me to a few questions:

1. Is there a standard way of getting the directory path with a native namespace package?
2. Why are there duplicate entries in the `__path__` attribute?

---

**My Solution**

I just converted the `__path__` to a `List[str]` without duplicates like so:

```py
paths: List[str] = list(set(foo.bar.__path__))
```

This works fine for me.  I am wondering if there's a more standard way to go about this.

Comment: "to ultimately get the `foo.bar` directory path" - there is *no such thing* as the `foo.bar` directory if `foo.bar` is a namespace package. The whole point of namespace packages is to split a package across *multiple* directories.

Comment: If you did not already realize that, then you almost certainly shouldn't be using namespace packages at all.

Comment: (As for the duplicate entries, you probably screwed up `sys.path` - there are likely duplicate entries there as well.)

Comment: There were some duplicate entries in `sys.path`, I agree that's the origin of the duplicates in `__path__`.